How to toggle display brightness using the physical button on Acer Aspire ZC-105?
While I had Windows on my All-in-one PC (Acer Aspire ZC-105) I was able to turn off the monitor* and keep processes running by clicking a button at the front of the computer.
After switching to Lubuntu this button does not work, and the only way to turn off the display (without shutting down the PC) has been to suspend it. Suspending doesn't work for me long term as I want to keep the ability to remote into it at any time as well as have a few background processes running 24/7.
While searching for the solution, I learned that All-In-One PCs don't really have the possibility to turn off the monitor because it is all integrated, so I assume it was actually doing something else that effectively made it so nothing was being displayed
Considering this, I want to use this button to toggle brightness between 0 and whatever it was previously (i.e. button press will set brightness from x to 0, next press will reset it back to x).
System Information:
Acer Aspire ZC-105 All-in-one Desktop
Lubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
LXQt 0.17.0
Qt 5.15.3

As suggested in this comment, I attempted to press the button in the shortcut manager, but no button press was registered. Maybe this is because the display toggle button is not a part of the keyboard?

The display toggle button at the front of the PC:


You've not provided any Lubuntu release details; but you can program a shortcut for almost any key you have; https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/F/keyboard_shortcuts.html show what is included for 24.04 LTS; but just add a new shortcut and have it run a script to set backlight/brightness to 0 as works best for your hardware (this should be specifically set for your device I'd recommend)

I suggest applying security upgrades asap; as 22.04.4 implies you're a little behind if your details are accurate.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/09/13/ubuntu-22-04-5-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date of 22.04.5, but installed systems (Lubuntu is a Ubuntu system) upgraded to it before that date.

Yes, it had been a while since I last used this computer. I have now upgraded it to 22.04.5
As for the shortcut, I have figured out that it is the brightness that I need to set to 0, but am unsure of how to capture the button press, and also do not know which button it is that I need to capture (xev did not detect the button)

From the Grub menu, press the e key on your keyboard. Then use the arrow keys to navigate down to where you see "quiet splash" and enter acpi_osi=Linux before the word quiet and when you are done, I believe you press x to boot Ubuntu. After you boot into Ubuntu, does the key work now?

When adding a shortcut you have the option of hitting a key, so have you tried just trying to use the key you want?  The Lubuntu 22.04 LTS manual is no longer available (in published form anyway & I can't recall if anyone else made it available) so I can't confirm if this was a feature on older released LXQt or only added via backports for 22.04/jammy.

Yes, to add to what guiverc said, I think this usually displays as "grab key combo" when trying to add or edit the existing key combo (displayed on the right).

Another option would be to try using acpi_backlight=vendor from the Grub menu as described in my previous comment. iirc, I had to use this option on an acer laptop.

When I go into monitor settings -> Info, I see:
Name: AIO LCD
Vendor: DO NOT USE - RTK
Does that have any implications for your above comment @mchid ?

If the button doesn't work, then let's try something different. Does the command xscreensaver-command -activate blank the screen for you? Also, test if you can still remote into the computer when the screen is blank (you should be able to because it's just a screensaver).

Of course, if the command is not available, simply install it: sudo apt update and sudo apt install xscreensaver

I went ahead and added that as an answer.

Go into your system settings, keyboard, shortcuts or search for your keyboard shortcut settings for Lubuntu.
In your keyboard shortcut settings, create a new shortcut. Use "screensaver" as the name and or description. Add the following command for the command:
xscreensaver -activate

And for the key combo, you should be able to "grab key" and hopefully, this will accept the screen button as a grab key combo.
If not, then use a key combo like CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+DownArrow instead. I've found this combo to turn the screen off is easy to remember and doesn't usually conflict with any existing keyboard shortcuts. Of course, you can use whatever combo you want, but just make sure the keybinding is not already in use or it will likely not work when you press the keys.
